# Is ternary operator available in stibo MDM?

Tags: master-data-management

I'm new to Stibo MDM. For some requirement i'm writing javascript to check the condition (Business Condition) and this condition will return true/false. I want to generate logger message for both true and false value. I have used ternary operator for this but getting syntax error i.e ? and : is not recognizing. 
How can i use this operator in stibo MDM

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ternary operator just as you would elsewhere for JavaScript. STEP uses the Mozilla JavaScript engine so pretty much anything that's valid there should work.

As an example, this definitely works:

```
var testVal = "a";
var isA = testVal == "a" ? true : false;    // Result is true
```